# Function using If statement does not get executed

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I am using package `dplyr` from R. I read textbook and online articles, but I just cannot figure out why this function is not working. Can someone please point out how to fix my function?

```
##creating dataset - this dataset is ranked by group (ID)
dt <- data.frame(
    ID = c('A1','A2','A4','A2','A1','A4','A3','A2','A1','A3'),
    Value = c(4,3,1,3,4,6,6,1,8,4));
dt2<-transform(dt, order.by.group = 
    ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))


##This function does not work, but it's supposed to create dt3 which is based
##on condition such as "best","worst" ranking etc in each ID group

test<- function(num="best") {
    if (num=="best") {
        dt3<-filter(dt2,order.by.group==1)}
    else if (num=="worst") {
        #sort to make low rank come to the last row position
        dt2<-arrange(dt2,ID,order.by.group)
        # Select the last row by id
        dt3<-dt2[!duplicated(dt2$ID, fromLast=TRUE), ]}
    else {dt3<-filter(dt2,order.by.group==num)}
}
```

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I don't think "=" works.. I get error message saying Error: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I checked ?filter and example usage. I see "filter(mtcars, cyl == 8)" so I think it's used like that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm using dplyr package from R. I also cleared my work space, but I don't get your error msg. I literally don't get anything and it doesn't execute. Let me restart R and run the code again.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Oh ok. When I run test("best") or test(2), it just doesn't produce dt3 and I also don't get any error msg either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about now?

```
test<- function(num="best") {
  if (num=="best") {
    dt3<-filter(dt2,order.by.group==1)
    } else if (num=="worst") {
    #sort to make low rank come to the last row position
    dt2<-arrange(dt2,ID,order.by.group)
    # Select the last row by id
    dt3<-dt2[!duplicated(dt2$ID, fromLast=TRUE), ]
    } else {
    dt3<-filter(dt2,order.by.group==num)
    }
 return(dt3)
 }
```

You function just seems to lack a `return` statement.

---

**update:**

> Oh this solves the issue for my purpose. But I still wonder why object `dt3` is not appearing in global environment. I mean when I type `dt2` in the console, it shows the results there, but when I type `dt3`, it says "Error: object 'dt3' not found"

When you call the function, do `dt3 <- test()`. The `dt3` inside the function is a **local variable**; it is destroyed on exit of function. However, by explicit assignment: `dt3 <-`, a variable `dt3` is created in global environment accepting the return value of the function.

The scope of a variable not only applies to R, but all programming languages.

Comment: Oh this solves the issue for my purpose. Thanks! but I still wonder why object dt3 is not appearing in global environment. I mean when I type "dt2" in the console, it shows the results there, but when I type "dt3", it says "Error: object 'dt3' not found"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It's so clear now! Very much appreciated!